# Структура и свойство

Tags: c#, .net, struct

```
using System;
struct a
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public static int operator +(a A, a A1)
    {
        return A.X + A1.X;
    }
}
class b
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a x;
        a y;
        x.X = 4;
        y.X = 6;
        Console.WriteLine(x + y);
    }
}
```

Скажите пожалуйста, почему компилятор пристает с тем, что x и y не присвоено значение ?? О каком значении идет речь ?? Если выходит, что таким образом создаются объекты структур, далее единственное поле структуры я инициализирую, но тем не менее компил. ругается, почему ???

Comment: klopp, спасибо за исправление, а то я пробовал написать по-нормальному, а выходила каша

Comment: @polyakov_s, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нельзя использовать свойства в структурах до того, как все поля структуры будут инициализированы. Используйте конструктор для инициализации полей структуры, если планируете обращаться к ним через свойства. Например, так:

```
using System;

struct a {

    public int X { get; set; }

    public static int operator +(a A, a A1) {
        return A.X + A1.X;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        a x = new a();
        a y = new a();
        x.X = 4;
        y.X = 6;
        Console.WriteLine(x + y);
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/nCLRl6

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943151/how-to-initialize-a-struct-in-c-sharp

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил замечательный совет из вашего источника: не стоит использовать мутабельные структуры.

    struct A
    {
        public A(int value) : this() { X = value; }
        public int X { get; private set; }
        public static A operator + (A left, A right)
        {
            return new A(left.X + right.X);
        }
    }